# How can moment.js be imported with typescript?

Tags: typescript, momentjs, jspm

I'm trying to learn Typescript. While I don't think it's relevant, I'm using VSCode for this demo.

I have a `package.json` that has these pieces in it:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jspm": "^0.16.33",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10"
  },
  "jspm": {
    "moment": "npm:moment@^2.12.0"
  }
}
```

Then I have a Typescript class `main.js` like this:

```
import moment from 'moment';
export class Main {
}
```

My `gulpfile.js` looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var typescript = require('gulp-tsb');
var compilerOptions = {
                        "rootDir": "src/",
                        "sourceMap": true,
                        "target": "es5",
                        "module": "amd",
                        "declaration": false,
                        "noImplicitAny": false,
                        "noResolve": true,
                        "removeComments": true,
                        "noLib": false,
                        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
                        "experimentalDecorators": true
                      };
var typescriptCompiler = typescript.create(compilerOptions);
gulp.task('build', function() {
  return gulp.src('/src')
    .pipe(typescriptCompiler())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/dest'));
});
```

When I run gulp build, I get the message: `"../main.ts(1,25): Cannot file module 'moment'."`

If I use `import moment = require('moment');` then jspm will work and bring in the module when I run the application, but I'm still receiving the build error.
I also tried:

```
npm install typings -g
typings install moment --ambient --save
```

Instead of making the problem better though, it got worse. Now I get the above error on build as well as the following: `"../typings/browser/ambient/moment/index.d.ts(9,21): Cannot find namespace 'moment'."`

If I go to the file provided by typings and add at the bottom of the file:

```
declare module "moment" { export = moment; }
```

I can get the second error to go away, but I still need the require statement to get moment to work in my `main.ts` file and am still getting the first build error.

Do I need to create my own `.d.ts` file for moment or is there just some setup piece I'm missing?

Comment: Adding this update for anyone who runs into this now: `import moment, { Moment } from 'moment';` allows you to do `const x = moment();` and `const x: Moment = moment();`

Comment: None of these solutions worked, I've moved here - https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns

Answer (score 148, accepted):

***Update***

Apparently, moment now provides its own type definitions (according to [sivabudh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38251719/4068027) at least from 2.14.1 upwards), thus you do not need `typings` or `@types` at all.

`import * as moment from 'moment'` should load the type definitions provided with the npm package.

*That said however, as said in [moment/pull/3319#issuecomment-263752265](https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/3319#issuecomment-263752265) the moment team seems to have some issues in maintaining those definitions (they are still searching someone who maintains them)*.

---

You need to install `moment` typings without the `--ambient` flag.

Then include it using `import * as moment from 'moment'`

Comment: That worked. Can you explain the difference between using the `--ambient` flag and not? I got numeraljs to work using the ambient flag. Also, their main page https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings gives the example using the ambient flag. I don't know when I would want/need to use one over the other. Thanks!

Comment: To be honest, I can't. Normally you use the `--ambient` flag for all Typescript definitions from `typings`/`DefinitelyTyped` but the `moment` definition has some strange structure and the files are not downloaded correctly. If you look at the definition file [moment.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/cc3d223a946f661eff871787edeb0fcb8f0db156/moment/moment.d.ts) it only contains a reference to the node version, which is not resolved on download (might be worth opening an issue).

Comment: Apparently there already is one relating to this issue: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/8388

Comment: And possibly a pull request to fix it: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/8975/files

Comment: I got it to work using
    import * as moment from 'moment/moment'
b/c it was installed as a subfolder in the node-modules folder.

Comment: I am on a webpack, and moment version 2.17.1 but still can not get it to work. I tried: import * as moment from 'moment'; and import * as moment from 'moment/moment'; and not working!

Comment: @MohyEldeen since this might need some troubleshooting feel free to step by in [this chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134151/typescript-moment-import-error-troubleshooting)

Comment: While this works, doesn't it make treeshaking impossible? Won't this include far more than I need?

Comment: @adamdport If you want tree shaking, then you will have to look at `lodash-es` library instead

Comment: Broken in Angular6. `Cannot call a namespace ('moment')`

Comment: Note, for this to work the "moduleResolution" TypeScript compiler option must be set to "node".

Answer (score 72):

You need to import *moment()* the function and *Moment* the class separately in TS.

I found a note in the typescript docs [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-function-d-ts.html).

> /*~ Note that ES6 modules cannot directly export callable functions
>   *~ This file should be imported using the CommonJS-style:
>   *~   import x = require('someLibrary');

So the code to import moment js into typescript actually looks like this:

```
import { Moment } from 'moment'
....
let moment = require('moment');
...
interface SomeTime {
  aMoment: Moment,
}
...
fn() {
  ...
  someTime.aMoment = moment(...);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Good answer since it shows the difference between the type and the function. Thanks!

Comment: cannot find name 'require'

Comment: Now this can be used as `import * as moment from 'moment';` and then use `moment.Moment` for typings.

Comment: What worked for me was: import moment = require('moment');

Comment: Actually you can also use `moment.Moment` interface directly from namespace `moment`

Comment: In 2020, working on a shared library that' used with vue.js and node/ts.ed and this is the only solution that worked for me.  Spent half a day trying other things.  

``import { Moment } from 'moment';``
``let moment = require('moment');``

Answer (score 22):

Not sure when this changed, but with the latest version of typescript, you just need to use `import moment from 'moment';` and everything else should work as normal.

### UPDATE:

Looks like moment recent fixed their import.  As of at least `2.24.0` you'll want to use `import * as moment from 'moment';`

Comment: `import * as moment from 'moment'` will not work with typescript but `import moment from 'moment'` does.

Comment: It is working but I am getting time of GMT 0, but i need local time which is not working I also try with  moment().utc().format()  but it is returing the same result.

Comment: @kbhaskar as of the latest version of moment they've fixed their import.  See updated answer

Comment: I think this is pretty much it. The only additional step I had to do was add `esModuleInterop` set to `true` in my config, which I got from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49256040/a-namespace-style-import-cannot-be-called-or-constructed-and-will-cause-a-failu). Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

**via typings**

Moment.js now supports TypeScript in v2.14.1.

See: https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/3280

---

**Directly**

Might not be the best answer, but this is the brute force way, and it works for me.

1. Just download the actual `moment.js` file and include it in your project.
2. For example, my project looks like this:

`$ tree
    .
    ├── main.js
    ├── main.js.map
    ├── main.ts
    └── moment.js`

3. And here's a sample source code:

```

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

class HelloWorld {
    public hello(input:string):string {
        if (input === '') {
            return "Hello, World!";
        }
        else {
            return "Hello, " + input + "!";
        }
    }
}

let h = new HelloWorld();
console.log(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
```

4. Just use `node` to run `main.js`.

Comment: Yes I confirm this is the rught answer. Worked like a charm.

Comment: When I try to do this using npm i @types/moment, I receive an error: TypeScript error: src\app.ts(1,1): error TS7038: A namespace-style import cannot be called or constructed, and will cause a failure at runtime. on tsc -v 2.7.2

Answer (score 8):

I've just noticed that the answer that I upvoted and commented on is ambiguous. So the following is exactly what worked for me. I'm currently on Moment `2.26.0` and TS `3.8.3`:

In code:

```js
import moment from 'moment';
```

In TS config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    ...
  }
}
```

I am building for *both* CommonJS and EMS so this config is imported into other config files.

The insight comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49256040/a-namespace-style-import-cannot-be-called-or-constructed-and-will-cause-a-failu) which relates to using Express. I figured it was worth adding here though, to help anyone who searches in relation to Moment.js, rather than something more general.

Comment: then you can use `moment()` like normal instead of `moment.default()`

Answer (score 5):

**ES6 syntax:**

***1. install moment***

```
npm install --save moment
```

***2. Import "moment" in your typescript file***

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

Comment: This is not the proper way to import a module in typescript. Please consider updating your answer. Refer to this for confirmation: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/project/modules/external-modules

Answer (score 5):

Still broken? Try uninstalling `@types/moment`.

So, I removed `@types/moment` package from the `package.json` file and it worked using:

```js
import * as moment from 'moment'
```

Newer versions of `moment` don't require the `@types/moment` package as types are already included.