# Installing momentjs in typescript

Tags: momentjs

I am trying to install momentjs v2.13.0 using npm install and then using it in typescript file as the following.
      "@types/moment": "^2.13.0"

```
import { moment } from 'moment';
import { moment } from 'moment';
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

All the three options are not working when i am trying to import the module inside a custom namespace. The error is cannot find the name moment.

Can someone please help me in resolving this issue
Typescript Being used : 2.6.

I have tried to use the link which was provided as a possible duplicate but unsure about how to install the version v2. 14.1 for momentjs. If someone can help me with the installation steps or any link, it will be useful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can moment.js be imported with typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648231/how-can-moment-js-be-imported-with-typescript)

Comment: I tried using the answer provided in the above link, but not able to figure out how to install this version using npm install