# A namespace-style import cannot be called or constructed, and will cause a failure at runtime

Tags: typescript, express, typescript-typings

With TypeScript 2.7.2, in VSCode version 1.21 with @types/express and the code that follows, in some cases VSCode throws errors stating that

```
A namespace-style import cannot be called or constructed, and will cause a failure at runtime.
```

However on other machines with similar setups and similar `tsconfig.json` files the code just works. What is happening here...

```
import { Bank } from './Bank';
import * as Express from 'express';  <== errors here..

let app: Express.Express;
this.app = Express();                <== and here
```

Why is this happening?

TIA,

John.

Comment: In addition to @fathyb's answer you will probably need to enable `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` in your `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 174, accepted):

The error should only happen with `esModuleInterop: true`. Maybe VSCode is ignoring your `tsconfig.json` or another one with `esModuleInterop: true` is used.

For a definitive fix set the compiler option `esModuleInterop` to `true` and use `import express` instead of `import * as express`.

**The problem** :

The ES6 specification defines the notion of "namespace object". A namespace object is `namespaceObject` in this statement : `import * as namespaceObject from 'a-module'`. The `typeof` this object is `object`, you are not supposed to be able to call it.

You were using `import * as express` until now because `express` is a CommonJS module, for Node.js, it is exported using `module.exports`. However it is illegal in the ES6 spec, and TypeScript now warns you.

**The solution** :

Setting `esModuleInterop` to true will make TypeScript wrap your `import` calls to check if the module is an ES6 module or a CommonJS. If it's a CommonJS module and you are using `import default from 'module'` TypeScript will find out and return the correct CommonJS module.

From the [TypeScript release note](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html) :

> Note: The new behavior is added under a flag to avoid unwarranted
>   breaks to existing code bases. We highly recommend applying it both to
>   new and existing projects. For existing projects, namespace imports
>   (import * as express from "express"; express();) will need to be
>   converted to default imports (import express from "express";
>   express();).

Comment: The line that helped me the most from the linked release notes was "Under the new --esModuleInterop flag, these callable CommonJS modules must be imported as default imports...", with an example of `import express from "express"`.  This of course fails if `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` isn't `true`, which basically means that flag is required to consume callable modules.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been getting these kinds of errors when using `momentjs` and your answer is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Helped me solve issues with momentjs as well, I used import this way: `import  moment, { Moment } from 'moment';`

Comment: Yes, thank you! MomentJs was causing this issue for me as well.

Comment: Somehow I'm still getting this error with both of the below

`"esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`
any ideas?

Comment: @Chima Did you find any solution? It failed for me too even after enabling both together?

Comment: @RohitMittal i didn't unfortunately - i just left it as require

Comment: @RohitMittal I had the same issue and I think I have a solution (that still uses ES6 modules) - see my answer.

Answer (score 22):

In my case I already had `"esModuleInterop": true` enabled in `tsconfig.json`. I needed to convert:

`import * as assert from "assert";`

to:

`import assert from "assert";`

Comment: After doing the suggestion in the selected answer, it did not work for me still... However, this change, worked!

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
import express = require('express');
```

Comment: It is not weird. TypeScript supports this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require

Comment: Yes, but newer build systems such as esbuild unfortunately don't