# Cannot import 'socket.io-client' as module in typescript

Tags: typescript, socket.io

I have added @types/socket.io-client module using npm

```sh
npm install --save @types/socket.io-client
```

After that import in my file datapulse.ts like that

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client'
export class DataPulseProvider {
    private socket: any;
    public constructor(socketServer: string) {
       this.socket = io(socketServer);
    }
// do something
}
```

But when I build my project I got an error

```
[!] Error: Cannot call a namespace ('io')
```

Anyone have some experience with socket.io-client with typscript, please help me resolve above issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Following the [socket.io ES6 import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client) you would do:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io('http://localhost');
```

In short, you have to do it as the old way:

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
```

is not compliant with ES6 and in the addition `io` is not callable anymore (it can be only object according to the ES^ namespacing specification):

```
// reports TS error
io(/* ... */);
```

So you have to extend `tsconfig.json` so TS will wrap for you the callable `io` into an object and make everything valid again:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "esModuleInterop_comment": "Necessary for incompatible modules to import, like socket.io",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        // ...
    },
,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports_comment": "cannot be false, as needed for `esModuleInterop` parameter, though we can omit it",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    // ...
}
```

This can also be helpful regarding namespacing:

- [A namespace-style import cannot be called or constructed, and will cause a failure at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49256040/a-namespace-style-import-cannot-be-called-or-constructed-and-will-cause-a-failu)

And this regarding the `esModuleInterop` parameter:

- [TS compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)
- [Understanding esModuleInterop in tsconfig file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238356/understanding-esmoduleinterop-in-tsconfig-file)

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with `socket.io-client`, but as per npmjs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client), you have to import `io` like this:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
```

It tells me that this library has one function with the `export default` keywords. But you use `import * as io`, which means that you want to import the entire module - an object that includes the default and named exported members, and you want to refer to this object as `io`.

Comment: Thanks @Yakov Fain, but @types/socket.io-client does not has any functions with `export default` so I cannot import like you above.

Comment: Their d.ts file doesn't use ES6 modules https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/socket.io-client/index.d.ts. I may be old and doesn't match the actual implementation of the library.  Try ```import io = require("io");```

Comment: I've tried as your suggestion but it got an error `Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.`

Comment: Looks like a mismatch between the actual code and d.ts. Just declare the variable io of type any and use socket.io-client without IDE help.

Comment: I declared like that
`var io: any;
io = require('socket.io-client');`
but it got another error
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

As the Socket.io Documentation says (nowadays) the types module isn't needed anymore. Uninstall it to get rid of the error.

> Note for TypeScript users: the types are now included in the socket.io-client package and thus the types from @types/socket.io-client are not needed anymore and may in fact cause errors:
> ~ [Docs](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-installation/)

A correct import would look like this

```
// ES6 import or TypeScript
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
// CommonJS 
const io = require("socket.io-client");
```

~ [Docs client-initialization](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-initialization/)

the @types/socket.io-client package was causing me troubles that's why I searcht for a solution and found another [Stack Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64813213/getting-error-while-calling-io-in-socket-io-client-angular-8) where they had trouble with errors on the import