# Getting error while calling IO in socket.io-client, angular 8

Tags: angular, socket.io

I am calling IO of socket.io-client in my angular project like below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketclientService {
  socket:any;
  url:any="ws://localhost:8080"
  constructor() {
    this.socket = io(this.url);
   }
   
   listen(eventname:any,data:any){
     return new Observable((subscriber)=>{
       this.socket.on(eventname,(data:any)=>{
         subscriber.next(data);
       })
     })
   }
   emit(eventname:string,data:any){
     this.socket.emit(eventname,data);
   } 
}
```

But I am always getting an error like:

```
 Error: src/app/services/socketclient.service.ts:11:19 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
      Type 'typeof import("C:/somepathtoproject/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/index")' has no call signatures.
    
    11     this.socket = io(this.url);
                         ~~
```

I am not getting it why this is showing, even I have installed @types/socket.io-client

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In angular 10 works fine:

```
import {io} from 'socket.io-client';
```

This is the official documentation
https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/index.html

Comment: VSCode is giving me the following warning: `Module '"socket.io-client"' has no exported member 'io'.ts(2305)` but everything is working fine.

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Works perfectly

Comment: And he also has to change the type of the socket to socket: Socket that is imported from the same dependency.

Comment: @ViniciusArruda and others: That is caused by manually installed type definitions. But they are included in the npm package now. So just remove them: `npm uninstall @types/socket.io-client`.

Answer (score 10):

That may be caused by the type definitions been installed separately. But they are shipped with the `socket.io-client` package now ([see docs: "Note for TypeScript users"](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-installation/)).

So just uninstall them and change the imports:

`npm uninstall @types/socket.io-client`

```typescript
import { io, Socket } from 'socket.io-client';
```

Answer (score 6):

I found a workaround for this, I explored the socket.io-client modules a bit and under 'index.d.ts' I found this line:

```
export { lookup as io, Socket, SocketOptions };
```

So I tried importing like this:

```
import {io} from 'socket.io-client/build/index';
```

then to use it:

```
this.socket=io(url);
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a 2021 updated way of doing this with Typescript:

```js
import { io, Socket } from 'socket.io-client';

export default class SocketService {
  socket: Socket;

  constructor(conn) {
    this.socket = io(conn);
 
   (...)
  }
}
```

One should import the `io` inside the brackets and also attribute the socket with the `Socket` type also comming from `'socket.io-client'`.

Answer (score 2):

Your import statement is incorrect, it should look like this

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
```

If you look into [type definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/socket.io-client/index.d.ts#L8) you can see that it is declared as

```
declare module 'socket.io-client' {
 export = io;
}
```

which according to [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require) means that it

> The export = syntax specifies a single object that is exported from the module

which if I understand correctly is similar to [default export](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#default-exports) that require above import syntax

Answer (score 2):

even I am also facing the same issues from last 2 days, Here is how I tackled this issue:

-> import * as io from 'socket.io-client'; //gives error in newer version, not sure why.

so use-> import {io} from 'socket.io-client'; //it will not throw any error

1)Firstly the error is because of newer version of socket.io-client(i,e version>3.0- which got released few days back). So try using the most stable.(I used 2.3.0 both in client & in server side)
2)Make sure that the socket version which you are using in client side matches with the socket version used in server.

Comment: I am using const io= require('socket.io-client)

Comment: import {io} ... is cousing this issue "Module '"socket.io-client"' has no exported member 'io'.ts(2305)"

Comment: ok, this problem is only on typescript if you have installed @types/socket.io-client

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your code is correct but I believe you are using the updated version of the socketIO which is (3.0) client.

Use the below version :
paste the entry in the package.json and run npm i.

```
**"socket.io-client": "2.2.0"**,
```

or simply remove the earlier version and install the 2.0 version.

```
$npm i socket.io-client@2.2.0 --save
```

Answer (score 1):

Install the following versions for the above example

$npm i socket.io-client@2.2.0 --save

Answer (score 0):

changing import statement to

```
import {io} from 'socket.io-client';
```

works fine for `"socket.io-client": "^4.3.2"` and above

while starting connection, use this statement:

```
    this.socket = io(< server url >, {query: { <your data object> });
```

in previous version, query key used to accept string and objects, now it shows type error for string