# Date time format in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, timezone, utc, date-formatting

I have been trying to format the date as 2018.05.30-12:00:07 +0530 in typescript using different DateTime (Timezone) formats but have been unable to do so. DateFormat as "YYYY.MM.DD-HH:mm:ss ZZZ" doesn't seem to work as well. Can someone please guide me to the right way to implement this?

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Look at momentjs and then since you're using typescript I'd recommend you look at the following post for importing moment into your typescript code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648231/how-can-moment-js-be-imported-with-typescript/38251719