# How to call moment function in angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

I have installed `moment.js` using

```
 npm i  moment
```

Included it in scripts and also tried importing in module.ts

When I am trying to call moment in `component.ts` it gives an error as

> 'cannot find name as moment'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: specifying "moduleResolution": "node" in the tsconfig.

Comment: You should also show how you are currently using it. Show related code.

Comment: its there already

Comment: I do not see any related code in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can moment.js be imported with typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648231/how-can-moment-js-be-imported-with-typescript)

Comment: @Amit Im am using like this let date= moment(new Date());

Answer (score 1):

import in your component

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

and you can call like this

```
moment(new Date)
```

Comment: did in the same way

Comment: use import  moment from 'moment'; remove "* as"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the following:

`npm install moment --save`

`npm install @types/moment --save`

Then in the angular-cli.json add to the scripts tag:

`"scripts:" ["../node_modules/moment/min/moment/min"]`

Then include in component:

`import * as moment from 'moment'`

Then use in the component method:

`let now = moment();`

`console.log(now.format());`

Comment: thanks suraj yes just checked => Moment provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/moment installed now.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure you have installed and saved `moment.js`.

```
npm i moment --save
```

Within your `component.ts`, import moment as followed:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

//You should capable to use momentjs as followed.
console.log(moment(moment.now())).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

> Note: If you have trouble importing moment, try adding "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true in compilerOptions in your tsconfig.json file and then use the syntax

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

[Reference](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/)

Comment: This is for the latest moment v2.13.0+ which includes the typescript definitions.

Comment: Try to use the `tsc` cli and show us your `tsconfig.json`. What version of typescript are you using?