# TypeScript - Global import doesn't work for MomentJS

Tags: typescript, webpack, momentjs

TypeScript provides an option to define global external modules. For example, if I have jQuery library loaded externally, I can set up global definition without including it's duplicate into TypeScript bundle. But when I try to do the same for 'moment' module, compiler doesn't import it's typing.

Here is my content of `tsconfig.json`, `compilerOptions` section

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": ["jquery", "moment"]
}
```

Here is code fragment that uses these definitions:

```
console.log($);
console.log(moment); // error TS2304: Cannot find name 'moment'
```

So it works fine for jQuery but not for MomentJS. I also have `@types/jquery` and `moment` added to `package.json` and installed into `node_modules`.

I know it's possible to use ES6 import syntax but it will include it into a bundle and I want to avoid it because it's already loaded in another place of the app.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36648231/4131048) question can be useful.

Comment: No, it's a different case

Answer (score 0):

```
 var moment;
```

At the top of your file.

Comment: it won't work for a huge project, and I definitely don't want to add it to every single file