# Conversion to Typescript for Antdesign Datepicker

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I can't figure out how to annotate `dateObj` parameter in `handleDateChange` function I've

**App.tsx**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css'; 
import { DatePicker } from 'antd';       // for css
import moment from 'moment';

const App = () => {
    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date())
    const handleDateChange = (dateObj: Date, dateStr: string) => {
        setDate(dateObj);
    }
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <DatePicker defaultValue={moment(date)} onChange={handleDateChange} />
            <header className="App-header">
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                <p>
                    Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
                </p>
                <a
                    className="App-link"
                    href="https://reactjs.org"
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >
                    Learn React
                </a>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Here's what tslint says -

> Type '(dateObj: Date, dateStr: string) => void' is not assignable to type '(date: Moment, dateString: string) => void'.
>     Types of parameters 'dateObj' and 'date' are incompatible.
>       Type 'Moment' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
>         Property 'toDateString' is missing in type 'Moment'

But I'm not sure how to overcome this.

Comment: Moment provides their own typings, I've never tried it personally, but check if this helps you out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45584936/236205

Answer (score 2):

Just this was required.

```
 const [date, setDate] = useState(moment(new Date()));
 const handleDateChange = (dateObj: moment.Moment, dateStr: string): void => {
    setDate(dateObj);
}
```

and then

```
 <DatePicker defaultValue={date} onChange={handleDateChange} />
```

There is no need to do a separate import for `Moment` as the `interface` and NOT `class` exists on moment namespace as per this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648231/how-can-moment-js-be-imported-with-typescript/45584936#45584936)

Answer (score 1):

Just pushing this answer into this topic as it seems to solve this issue and was not marked as correct answer in the other question: [How can moment.js be imported with typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648231/how-can-moment-js-be-imported-with-typescript/45584936#45584936)

---

You need to import *moment()* the function and *Moment* the class separately in TS.

I found a note in the typescript docs [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-function-d-ts.html).

> /*~ Note that ES6 modules cannot directly export callable functions.
>    *~ This file should be imported using the CommonJS-style:
>    *~   import x = require('someLibrary');

So the code to import moment js into typescript actually looks like this:

```
import { Moment } from 'moment'
....
let moment = require('moment');
...
interface SomeTime {
  aMoment: Moment,
}
...
fn() {
  ...
  someTime.aMoment = moment(...);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i try this one [answer reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53994543/11548416), and got warning like this:

[image: images error]

and i fix with this:

```
const [date, setDate] = useState<moment.Moment | null>(moment(new Date()))
  const handleDateChange = (dateObject: moment.Moment | null, dateString: string): void => {
    console.info('date string:', dateString)
    console.info('date obj:', dateObject)
    setDate(dateObject)
  }
```

hope this one help you who facing this warning while trying to implement **antd datepicker** in typescript

Answer (score 0):

For everyone wondering what you should after migrating to antd v5, follow @muhammad-irva answer above and replace `dateObject: moment.Moment` by `dateObject: Dayjs | null`