# Pass date without timezone

Tags: typescript, aspnetboilerplate

Problem with moment in asp.net boilerplate Angular version. 
Basically I'm passing date to my API. But after date passed trough service proxy date converted to ISO(UTC) and it brakes the logic. For example I pass date of 28 February after it converts to UTC my backend got 27 February. 
As I understand i need to remove timezone offset from my date and i need to use utc() method of moment but i can't make this work.

I Import moment in my ts file as import * as moment from 'moment';

I casting value as

```
let licDate = (this.newExpireDateField.value as moment.Moment).utc(false));
```

I'm using aot compilation, so there is no problem during compilation, but when this line called in browser it throws exception
ERROR TypeError: this.newExpireDateField.value.utc is not a function

I guess it tries to call this function from moment-timezone types there is no utc function in there. But why it called this from other type that i specify?

FYI I can't use any method from moment lib here. It trows exception  "is not a function". Maybe it somehow related to webpack. Please help solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
moment.utc().format('MM-DD-YYYY')
```

returns "2019-02-04"

Comment: Read my problem carefully. It can't find method.  utc is not a function.

Comment: Then you need to make sure you've correctly imported moment. What version are you on?

Comment: "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648231/how-can-moment-js-be-imported-with-typescript

As long as you've correctly imported the object you shouldn't have any issues formatting it like I've mentioned.

Comment: You should search Stack Overflow and google before posting.

Comment: (this.newExpireDateField.value as moment.Moment) -> idk what you're trying to do there.... When posting on Stack Overflow it's best to provide a code snippet that can be run and highlight what you're having trouble with.

Comment: The problem comes from two type definitions. There are moment and moment-timezone. And it looks that after compilation it use type of moment-timezone instead of moment itself. That the reason why it can't find any functions from moment. But why it happen and how to fix it.

Comment: I don't think you're using moment correctly and you really haven't provided an example that I can help with.

Comment: Let's wait answer from aspnetboilerplate team. They are setup all scripts. Maybe they can help to understand. I can't give you a snippet because i can't reproduce it aside. When I setup this into separate project from scratch it works fine. But exactly in this project (Asp.net boilerplate) doesn't. I've tried to remove node_modules folder and install again.It doesn't work also.

Comment: You could make it a repo on github and link to it so people and download and build it using your package.json file. You CAN provide an example and if you need help that is best practice.

Comment: found. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake. 
There was typecasting issue.

When I used to

```
let licDate = (this.newExpireDateField.value as moment.Moment)
```

it casted to plain date type of JS. 
After I've change it to:

```
let newDate: moment.Moment = moment(this.newExpireDateField.value);
```

it start working exactly as moment type. Thanks guys for you help.