# Importing moment in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I imported moment in angular 6:

```
import moment from 'moment'
```

and

```
let formatted = moment(startDate).tz(timezone).format();
```

which seems to work fine...but **ng serve** outputs the following error:

```
Module '"/my/project/node_modules/moment/moment"' has no default export.
```

OK, I understand this error; it says that moment is not exported as default...but when I try to export this way:

```
import { moment } from 'moment'
```

but than, error says that moment is in fact an object, not a function.

How did it work in the first step than?
How should I import the "moment"?

**UPDATE**
I also tried as suggested in the other question...

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

But than I got the following result:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.
node_modules/angular-moment-timezone/node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can moment.js be imported with typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648231/how-can-moment-js-be-imported-with-typescript)

Comment: Consider using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) which is a modern rewrite of Moment.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Wow, useful!

Comment: No this is not a duplicate. The solution in that answer doesn't solve my problem. I explained with the *UPDATE*

Comment: Your issue is related to the library angular-moment-timezone, not moment specifically. Try using moment-timezone instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution...Firstly I suggest to [review this issue page](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/385).

1. I abandoned **angular-moment-timezone** and started using **moment-timezone**, the reason for ngDevMode error is angular-moment-timezone package has another node-modules inside it. This is a terrible package managing.
2. I than imported as:

   `import * as moment from 'moment';
    import 'moment-timezone';`

and now my code is working...also the project builds.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following to import moment:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Please see the update in my question, I also have a problem with this solution.

Comment: You’re indicating that if you remove this import and anything related to moment in your code, you do no see this issue when running build?

Comment: I can run the code with "import moment from 'moment'"...
but I can't build or start ng serve again. This is what I found strange.

Comment: That is a bigger issue potentially that can be resolved with updating versions of Angular. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21670

Comment: So your issue looks to be with angular-moment-timezone library specifically. Can you just use moment-timezone instead? Try even removing angular moment timezone and removing any code related to timezone and it should build.

Answer (score -5):

You can import moment directly in angular by using this:-

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```