# Use Moment in AngularDateRangePicker

Tags: c#, angular, npm

I have been trying to use AngularDateRangePicker as indicated in following url:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-daterangepicker-material
```

However when line

```
selected: {startDate: Moment, endDate: Moment};
```

doesnt work

I installed Moment as

```
npm install moment --save
```

and imported as

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

But I am still getting

```
Cannot use namespace 'moment' as a type.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change This

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

to

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

Comment: giving me:  This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45584936/14327478    Please see this Ans.