# Moment not found in 'moment' when importing {Moment} from 'moment'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, momentjs

In a reactJS project with typescript, I'm trying to import `moment` and the type `Moment`

Tried using `import moment, { Moment } from 'moment'`

But that makes ESLint unhappy: `ESLint: Moment not found in 'moment'(import/named)`

Tried to use `import * as moment from 'moment'`

And that makes typescript unhappy: `TS2349: This expression is not callable. Type 'typeof moment' has no call signatures.`

Technically I can't really find a way to import the `Moment` type easily.
This following line should be pretty simple but yet it's so difficult to find a solid way to import both `moment` and `Moment`

`const [date, setDate] = useState<Moment>(moment());`

Note: disabling the ESLint rule is not something I wanna do

Comment: What does "unhappy" mean? What are the actual errors/warnings?

Comment: Try "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true in tsconfig. Then see if `import moment from 'moment'` works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can moment.js be imported with typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648231/how-can-moment-js-be-imported-with-typescript)

Comment: @evolutionxbox I updated the question with the errors.
The funny thing is that if I use `import moment from 'moment'`I can use `moment.Moment` as a type :)

Answer (score 1):

After a quick search, you can do the following, according to this thread :[How can moment.js be imported with typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648231/how-can-moment-js-be-imported-with-typescript):

```
import { Moment } from 'moment'
let moment = require('moment');
```

Comment: Doesn't this make the question a duplicate?

Comment: Yes. What is the procedure then ?

Comment: If we believe the question to be answered by another, we "flag" it as a duplicate.

Comment: Oh ok I see. Thanks

Comment: @evolutionxbox sorry but I don't think any of these answers my question :) I read them all

Comment: Why it's not answering your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { default as moment, Moment } from 'moment'
```

should work as well, does that make typescript unhappy too? Been doing this for a while.

Comment: Interesting, why doesn't `import moment, { Moment } from 'moment'` work then?

Comment: With that I still get `ESLint: Moment not found in 'moment'(import/named)`

Comment: It's likely that moment doesn't use es modules. So it doesn't have a named export called `moment`

Comment: @evolutionxbox but `import moment from 'moment'` is not a named import, right? :)